# resetting the root password in linux

Tags: linux, passwords, fedora, root

How do I reset the root password in fedora ? Is there any way out ? I have googled a lot but couldn't find any useful result.

Comment: Do you just want to reset the password or do you not have it to begin with?

Comment: @MaQleod reset the password

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the [Fedora documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_reset_a_root_password) gives Information on how to reset the root password.

You can also use this more general approach [here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/Startup_and_shutdown/root_password_recovery.shtml#Using_init_bash_trick_in_grub) with init=/bin/bash which works
on about any distro.

This is from the [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword) documentation:

> 1. Reboot your computer
> 2. Press SHIFT or ESC at the grub prompt (as earlier).
> 3. Select your image.
> 4. Highlight the line that begins kernel and press 'e' to edit
> 5. Go to the very end of the line, change the ro to rw and add init=/bin/bash
>
> press enter, then press b to boot your system.
>
> Your system will boot up to a passwordless root shell.
>
> 6. Type in passwd username
> 7. Set your password.
> 8. Type in reboot

This should work,too

Answer (score 2):

#### With sudo access:

When you at least have `sudo` access to the machine you can use `sudo bash` to aquire a root shell and `passwd` afterwards.

#### With chroot:

Another way would be to boot from a LiveCD (or USB Stick with a live System). Then you have to mount your system partitions. At least the ones containing `/etc` and the location of `passwd`, probably `/bin` check with `which passwd`.
Afterwards you chroot into that directory.

```
 mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/system
 mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/system/etc
 chroot /mnt/system /bin/bash
```

Now you are virtually inside your new environment and can use `passwd`. Maybe you have to update your environment with `hash -r` before.

Answer (score 1):

This works in debian distros, should work in Fedora I think (assuming you have sudo privs)

> sudo passwd root

type and verify the new password and done.